# Is `this` a DOM object or a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am having a little difficulty understanding this jquery snippet. Particularly if a DOM object or a jquery object is used. 
Here is the code

```
$(".foo").click(function() {  
  var displayTool = $(this).find(".tool-name").text() //is this a jquery object or DOM object ?
});
```

My first question is if `this` is a DOM object or a jQuery Object? I would assume that it is a DOM object as we are passing it through a jQuery modifier in the next statement i.e `$(this).find(".tool-name")` to further extract data from it. Is that correct?

If so then my next question is why is `this` a DOM object? I was under the impression that jQuery functions always return jQuery objects for instance  `$(this).find(".tool-name")` should return a jQuery object and not a DOM object. I know we can extract DOM object from jQuery objects but I am not interested in that. I would like to know why `this` was a DOM object. In case I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: `console.log(this)`. it's a dom object because it doesn't necessarily need to be a jquery object. What if all you need was to get it's id? `this.id`. To get a real answer to that you'd have to ask the library authors, all we can do is speculate.

Comment: _this_ is a DOM object and it must be due by design to keep it in tune with _addEventListener_

Comment: Please, research how to debug using your browser's developer tools. Then you'll have all the answers.

Comment: Just read the manual :) [`.click(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) is a shorthand for [`.on("click", ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) -> _"When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events `this` is the element where the event was attached and for delegated events `this` is an element matching selector. (Note that `this` may not be equal to `event.target` if the event has bubbled from a descendant element.)"_

Comment: @Andreas so in short .click() actually returns a dom object and not a jquery object ?

Comment: @JamesFranco no.. `.click()` returns the same collection it was called on so that you can continue chaining. It's in the docs.

Comment: @KevinB ah ok that explains it. Can you put that as an aswer

Comment: I don't often post answers to questions that i cast close votes on.

Comment: to clarify, you've asked two unrelated questions (too broad). One of the two is poorly researched (a reason to downvote) and the other is primiarly opinion based (yet another close reason.)

Comment: @JamesFranco This could have easily been determined by the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator: `console.log(this instanceof $, this instanceof HTMLElement, this instanceof Element);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `this` is always a DOM object within a jQuery click handler.

As to *why* this is...

Do you always want a jQuery object containing the clicked element within a click handler? No, there are occasions when you do not. For example, say you wanted to remove another element from the page when an element was clicked:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $('.spinner').remove();
});
```

You never use `this`.

Or you may want simply to do something with the element's `id`:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

In neither case do you want to have a jQuery selection. And since building a jQuery selection is a relatively expensive operation, it is much better not to create it unless you explicitly say you want it by doing `$(this)`.

You might be thinking "ah, but we already built the selection in the original line of code":

```
 $(".foo").click(function() {
```

`.foo` means something different. It means "all the elements with the class `foo`", not "the element that was just clicked".